# Accessing raw camera feed in Unity Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, opencv, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

**Project Summary:**

I'm working on computer vision project for the Hololens 2, the goal is to be able to process frames from a live camera feed and then overlay the processed frames in AR within my Unity app.

> ex) The user will look at a crack in a surface, then the crack will be high-lighted in AR.

The image processing is done in C++ via openCV and will be built into a .dll to access within Unity, the problem I'm running into currently is accessing a raw camera feed from the Hololens that I can use for processing.

**Possibilities:**

I've looked into [Mixed Reality Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/mixed-reality-capture-overview) but this seems to mostly be used for recording/streaming headset view and not a raw camera feed. Holograms will also interfere with the image processing.

I've also looked into [Research Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/research-mode) which gives access to sensor streams such as the cameras and depth sensors used for tracking the headset, this is a possibility but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

**Camera stream requirements:**

- Doesn't need color, black and white is fine
- At least 30fps
- Raw camera feed without Holograms overlayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Research Mode can achieve your needs, but it should be noted that Research Mode is not suitable for production environments.

In addition to Research Mode, you can try **PhotoCapture** and **VideoCapture** provided by Unity, you can choose whether to capture holograms when calling **CreateAsync**. Please refer to the documentation below.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/locatable-camera-in-unity
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.CreateAsync.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.VideoCapture.CreateAsync.html

You can also try **WebCamTexture**, it doesn't capture holograms. You can refer to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html.